# CSS - Percentage height of mobile screen with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm guessing the answer to this is a no - but is there a clever way to calculate 2/3 height of the mobile screen?

I need a header div containing a background image to take up 2/3 of the screen height regardless of device - if at all possible a clean CSS only solution would be the ideal.

Currently I have

```
    <div class="twoThirds">
        <img src="headerimg.jpg" />  
    </div>
```

and the following LESS styles -

```
.twoThirds{


height:66%;
@media (max-width: 766px) {
    height:200px;
}
margin:0; 
padding:0;
width:auto;

img{

    width:100%;
    height:auto;

}

}
```

Comment: And where is the background image?

Comment: There is..you might want to look at viewport units but these relate to browser window size...not screen size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by *screen* you mean rather *viewport* then you could use viewport units

```
.twoThirds {
   height: 66.6vh;
}
```

Where `1vh` is `1/100` of the viewport height and `100vh` is the full viewport height.
Support across browser: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

For older devices, where these units are not (fully) supported, a possible workaround is to assign `height: 100%` to the `html` and `body` elements and `height: 66.6%` to the `.twoThird` element